# Recursively delete files from Windows SFTP server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssis, sftp, putty

I'm attempting to create a batch file within an SSIS script task that uses `psftp.exe`.  The batch file will connect to a remote SFTP server (running Windows XP) and recursively bring down files.  The files (but not their directories) should be deleted once the downloading has been accomplished.

The batch file calls `psftp.exe -b script`.  Within the script file, I can recursively bring down files with this command:

```
mget -r Share
```

(Share is the starting folder; the folder structure resembles):

```
.../Share/Client1
.../Share/Client2
```

However, I can't figure out how to delete the files that I've brought down.  If I could get a recursive move going it would work but it hasn't worked yet.  Same with a recursive delete after the 'mget' has been performed.

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: In a script file that Putty (i.e., psftp.exe) runs, this command recursively brings down files from a remote Windows server:
mget -r Share

(where Share is a directory on the remote server.)

However, what command enables me to delete the files after they've been brought down?  (Alternatively, what command allows me to recursively move them down?)

thanks,

Comment: SFTP does not have a concept of "move remote file to local" nor does it have a "recursive delete remote files". I think you're going to need to code some logic to find the file names first, store the list, iterate over the list to copy then delete the files. It's achievable in .bat but probably easier in Powershell or Python,

Comment: Fuzzyfelt, thanks a lot for the information.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP can do this with a -delete switch on the get command: www.winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_transfer_and_delete

WinSCP works well with SSIS using the Execute Process Task. Scripts are usually not required as you can string commands together using /command